# Hash password with another password

Tags: go, cryptography

I want to understand what is the best option to hash password with a different password.
What I mean by that - let's take standard encryption as an example:

```
package password

import "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"

func Hash(password string) (string, error) {
    bytes, err := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword([]byte(password), 14)
    return string(bytes), err
}

func Verify(hashed, password string) bool {
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword([]byte(hashed), []byte(password))
    return err == nil
}
```

Here I can generate a hash from the same password that I use to encrypt.
But what if for instance, I store other passwords like to my email configuration, payment details, etc?
How do I encrypt it in Golang with let's say this .env stored key `454ec400-2d9d-422d-940e-39eb2be0812e`?

Comment: The code you posted above does not do any encryption. You generate a hash from a password, and `Verify()` can tell if the given password equals to the original that you hashed before, knowing just the hash.

Comment: True but my question is if there is a way to do something like this: `bcrypt.GenerateWithPassword(passwordToHash, keyToUseToHashThePassword)`. Meaning, I want to create a hash for the password using another key that I can use to later `bcrypt.GetPassword(hash, key) string` where string is the password I encrypted

Comment: `bcrypt` is a one-way hash algorithm. If you want to encrypt, there are plenty algorithms for that, such as [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard).

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Hashing and encryption are different things used for different purposes. There is another cryptographic transform called a MAC -- short for Message Authentication Code -- that's like a hash but uses a secret symmetric key.